# Declaring variables in .h file in brackets

Tags: objective-c

What's going on inside the brackets when variables are declared inside the public interface of the .h file?  What is a case that you would do something like this?  It seems to me you should just make properties that are backed by these variables public and remove the variables from the .h file.

```
@interface GSFullscreenAdViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{

    /**
     * This view controller's view.
     */
    GSFullscreenAdView * m_adView;

    /**
     * The ad that is currently fetched or displaying. Resets to nil on ad dismissal.
     */
    GSFullscreenAd * m_currentAd;

    /**
     * The view controller that this GSFullscreenAdViewController is being
     * displayed from.
     */
    UIViewController * m_parentViewController;

    /**
     * Whether the ad is currently displaying
     */
    BOOL m_isDisplaying;

    /**
     * Whether the ad is currently animating onto the screen
     */
    BOOL m_isPresenting;

    /**
     * Whether the ad is in the process of being dismissed
     */
    BOOL m_isDismissing;

    UIImagePickerController * m_imagePickerController;
}

@property (readonly) GSFullscreenAdView * adView;
@property (readonly) BOOL isDisplaying;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL allowOrientationChange;
```

Comment: Please do some basic research before posting such questions. Any simple tutorial on Objective-C will answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to declare your instance variables in your `@implementation` section is actually a relatively new addition to Objective-C.  Before Xcode 4.2 (released 2011/10/12), you could only declare your instance variables in the `@interface` section.  Perhaps the code you're looking at was written before Xcode 4.2 (or later) was in wide use.

Check it yourself in the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays just declaring a property would do for most cases. For older versions of objective-c the corresponding iVar had to be declared manually. For doing so the iVar had to be declared within curly brackets before the property was declared.

Even today you may want so associate a property with a given iVar (by naming the iVar in the `@synthezise` statement. However, for that it should be sufficient to declare the iVar within curly brackets following the `@interface` statement. In those cases you could declare them within brackets following a second `@interface` statement in the .m file.

Well, it still works. Some oder tutorials still use this pattern. You or your team/company may still use older code that does this.

And finally it is hard, sometimes, to overcome an old peculiar :-)